# What is a data field?

Tags: java

I am supposed to Modify the Time2 class (below) to implement the time as the number of seconds since midnight. The class  should have one data field (an int  with the number of seconds since midnight) instead of three. This change should not affect the arguments , behavior , or output  of the public methods .

And then create a Driver class  with a main method  to test your Time2 class . This program  should ask the user to input the number of hours, minutes, and seconds past midnight, creating a Time2 object  and using the mutator methods . The program  should then use the toString() method  to print out the time.

My question is what part of the code below is the data field?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Time2 time = new Time2();

    System.out.print("Enter hours:");
    int hours = input.nextInt();                                
    System.out.print("Enter minutes:"); 
    int minutes = input.nextInt();                              
    System.out.print("Enter seconds:"); 
    int seconds = input.nextInt();

    time.setSecond(seconds);    
    System.out.println(time.toString());
}

public static class  Time2 {

private  int  hour; 
private  int  minute;
private  int  second;   

public Time2() {this(0, 0, 0);}
public Time2(int  hour) {this(hour, 0, 0);}
public Time2(int  hour, int  minute) {this(hour, minute, 0);}

public Time2(int  hour, int  minute, int  second) {
    if(hour<0||hour>=24)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour must be 0-23");
    if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minute must be 0-59");
    if (second < 0 || second >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("second must be 0-59");
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}

public Time2(Time2 time) {this(time.getHour(), time.getMinute(), time.getSecond());}

public void setTime(int  hour, int  minute, int  second) {
    if (hour<0||hour>=24)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour must be 0-23");
    if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("minute must be 0-59");
    if (second < 0 || second >= 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("second must be 0-59");
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}

public void setSecond(int  second) {
    if (second <= 0 || second > 60)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("second must be 0-59");
    this.second = second;
}

public int  getHour() {return second/60/60;}
public int  getMinute() {return second/60;}
public int  getSecond() {return second;}

public String  toUniversalString() {
    return String.format( "%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond());
}

public String  toString() {
    return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s",
                          ((getHour() == 0 || getHour() == 12) ? 12 : getHour() % 12), getMinute(),
                          getSecond(), (getHour() < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
}
}
}
```

~UPDATE~ I got the code to work, the only problem with it is that it displays to wrong hours and minute(see output link)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcYmx.png)

Comment: fields are properties of the class. in your example below are fields:
private  int  hour; // 0 - 23
private  int  minute;   // 0 - 59
private  int  second;   // 0 - 59

and you have to add something like private int secondsSinceMidNight; field which will hold calculated value based on hour,minute and seconds passed through the Time2 class.

you can create a method to do the calculation and call it from main method to get value for secondsSinceMidNight field (you can also call it variable).
hope you find it helpful

Comment: @LaxmanChari Thank you for the tips! They're very helpful:) I just wish that my instructor taught us what the statement `throw new IllegalArgumentException` means:/ Could this be combined into a single if statement?

Comment: [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html) explains exceptions. 
when you say `throw new IllegalArgumentException("hour must be 0-23");` you are instructing the program to stop execution from this point, since the input received is not as expected. each condition fails due to specific reason, in this example hours can be between 0-23 so your message is relevant only in this case.
if you have generic message then you can have only one if statement which throws the exception.

Comment: I apologize I am not sure how to approach this. Since in this case, the if statement can only take in one message, will an if else statement work? Im not sure how else I could do it.

Comment: the code is trying to determine if the input is valid. and in case if input is not valid user of the application should be shown a message that the input is not valid, with reason. since you have 3 fields, and each field can hold specific values e.g. hours can be between 0-23, minutes between 0-59 etc. you can write if statements to validate user inputs and  notify user where they are going wrong, so that they can correct the input and run program again.
if you run this code by passing 800 as value for hours it should fail the code execution and show message **hour must be 0-23** .

Comment: @LaxmanChari I got it to work:) the code above is updated. However, the hours and minutes is wrong. For example when the user enters 1 for hours, 35 for minutes, and 58 for seconds, it returns 12:00:58 instead of 1:35:58

Comment: you have to properly set values for fields in the Time2 class.
to do that either you can use constructor or setters.
you are using default constructor which sets all fields to 0.
then you user setter for seconds which sets the secods to the object.
what you can do is use `new Time2(hour, minute, second)` constructor after getting values for all the fields or use setters for all fields, so that the object is initialized properly.

Answer (score 3):

A "date field" or "data member" is a variable which is part of the class, and holds some data. In this case, you have three data fields - `hour`, `minute` and `second` (all `int`s). Your task is to replace this implementation with a single field, `second`, and adjust the methods' implementations accordingly so they will keep their behavior.

Comment: Would the code then get rid of `public int  getHour() {return hour;}`
`public int  getMinute() {return minute;}`?

Comment: @ally the requirement, as far as I understand it, is to keep these methods. You would have to change the implementation though. E.g. `public in getHour() { return second/60/60; }`.

Comment: I've edited my code however, it wont display the time.